# What happens when applying operations (+, -, *) with null values in Firebase rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

For example, what returns if I do something like:

```
".read" : "root.child('kid').val() - 1 > 0"
```

And the value of the `kid` node is null (maybe due to an empty `RuleDataSnapshot`, I mean, `kid` node doesn't exist)?

I couldn't find an answer [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#operators).